# How to make my slow ViewPager to work faster

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I've created `Activity` to handle `ViewPager`. At the beginning it was working fine, but then I had to add some more code, to make it refresh my pages while selecting them. I've handled it by calling `onResume()` method with every page change.

I've optimized my Fragments, cleared unnecessary code (`inside onResume()`) in each of them, but this give no result. That's how my Activity looks like:

```
public class MainTabsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FullList.OnListFragmentInteractionListener, AcceptedList.OnListFragmentInteractionListener, StartedList.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    private static final int NUM_TABS = 3;
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    TabLayout tabLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_tabs);

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));
        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i1) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int i) {
                Fragment fragment = ((SectionsPagerAdapter)mViewPager.getAdapter()).getFragment(i);

                if (fragment != null) {
                    Log.e("PAGE SELECTED", " " + i);
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(i).select();
                    fragment.onResume();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

            }

        });

        Intent i = getIntent();
        int pageNum = i.getIntExtra("pagenumber", 0);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(pageNum);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(pageNum).select();
        mViewPager.invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main_tabs, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListFragmentInteraction(DummyContent.DummyItem item) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private Map<Integer, String> mFragmentTags;
        private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            mFragmentTags = new HashMap<>();
            mFragmentManager = fm;
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

            switch(position) {
                case 0:
                    return getString(R.string.tab_text_1);
                case 1:
                    return getString(R.string.tab_text_2);
                case 2:
                    return getString(R.string.tab_text_3);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    FullList tab1 = new FullList();
                    return tab1;

                case 1:
                    AcceptedList tab2 = new AcceptedList();
                    return tab2;

                case 2:
                    StartedList tab3 = new StartedList();
                    return tab3;

                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_TABS;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
            Object obj = super.instantiateItem(container, position);
            if (obj instanceof Fragment) {
                Fragment f = (Fragment) obj;
                String tag = f.getTag();
                mFragmentTags.put(position, tag);
            }
            return obj;
        }

        public Fragment getFragment(int position) {
            String tag = mFragmentTags.get(position);
            if (tag == null) return null;
            return mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

I've added code, to call `onResume()` method, but funny thing is that the `Fragments` are loading so long only while I open this `Activity` from another, but not while scrolling between pages (everything works smoothly then), before changes everything was fine. 
Is there any way to make this work faster?

Comment: Why are you doing stuff in _onPageSelected_ method. It will give you current fragment. So exactly what do you want ?

Comment: User refresh data from `api`. Data is saved inside local `database` and displayed in `RecyclerView`. I don't know when data is being refreshed, so with every tab change I check only `database` item count and `Array` `size()`, if they are the same I do nothing more, but if they not I clear the `Array`, get new data set and notifiy the adapter. (I have 3 Recyclers in 3 tabs so I call `onResume()` at every tab)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write onPageSelected code to change your tab selection.

```
mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);   // this will synchronize our tablayout with your viewpager
```

You should not call `onResume` directly, this is a system event and a call to this void
 is not recommended.

Also, in your case, no need to call `mViewPager.invalidate()`

Comment: Inside on `Fragment` i have refresh `Button` which calls an api (retrofit2) and gets new data (if exist) and saving it into `database`. I am calling `onResume()` on tab selection because I need to refresh my `ArrayList`, and notify recycler adapter (only if there are new items to add - I am comparing old number of rows in database with new one). I don't know any other way to do that.